# R Code for a loop with subgrouped data

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have an r code question and I'm very inexperience when it comes to loops.  I would like to create a new column vector consisting of 0, 1, and 2's conditioned on other variables.

First, I will try to substantively explain my data.  My data consists of representatives and how long they stay on a committee.  My unit of analysis is congressional term.  If a members stays on their committee, then they receive a 0.  If they leave a committee during a congress, early, they receive a 2.  If a members does not leave a committee early, then they receive a 1.

I will now try to explain the technical aspects of my problem.  Subjects are given an identification number (ID).  If a "Cong" value is less than the maximum Cong value for a subject, then the new column should have a 0.  If a "Cong" value is less than the maximum "Cong" value for a subject, but the largest for a respective "comm", then receive a 2.  If a "Cong" value is equal to the maximum "Cong value for an individual, then they receive a 1.  An example might help.

```
ID  Cong  Comm
 1   52    3
 1   53    3
 1   54    3
 1   53    4
 2   50    2
 2   50    7
 3   48    4
 4   48    3
 4   48    7
 4   49    7
```

I would like for it to look like this.

```
 ID  Cong  Comm   Y
 1   52    3      0
 1   53    3      0
 1   54    3      1
 1   53    4      2
 2   50    2      1
 2   50    7      1
 3   48    4      1
 4   48    3      2
 4   48    7      0
 4   49    7      1
```

It was recommended that I use a loop, but I haven't been able to find any examples that are even remotely related to my data structure.    Should I create a new index? I would appreciate any R code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry for any confusion!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @coffeinjunky: I fear that `ifelse` would be a little tricky to use here...

Comment: Sounds like you should include the extra data in your table (like `max.Cong` in the form of reproducible code so that people can offer substantive advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this with three assignments I believe since your categories are hierarchical. Try

```
#sample data
data.frame(
    ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    Cong = c(52L, 53L, 54L, 53L, 50L, 50L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L), 
    Comm = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 7L)
)

dd$Y <- 0
dd$Y[dd$Cong==with(dd, ave(Cong, ID, Comm, FUN=max, drop=T))] <- 2
dd$Y[dd$Cong==with(dd, ave(Cong, ID, FUN=max))] <- 1
```

That returns

```
   ID Cong Comm Y
1   1   52    3 0
2   1   53    3 0
3   1   54    3 1
4   1   53    4 2
5   2   50    2 1
6   2   50    7 1
7   3   48    4 1
8   4   48    3 2
9   4   48    7 0
10  4   49    7 1
```

The idea is that the first assignment sets every Y to zero. The second assignment finds the highest Cong for each ID for each Comm and sets Y=1 if the Cong value matches the highest one for the group. We do the assignment one more time, now ignoring Comm. So if it's the highest Cong for an individual, it will over write the Y=1 with a Y=2. No loop needed.

Comment: @user3781111 if this answer is what you were looking for, consider accepting is as the solution to your problem by clicking the check mark below the answer score. It should turn green.